# PowerShell cmdlet to remove history of Windows Defender

Tags: command-line, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I am looking for command line or PowerShell cmdlet to delete/remove all the history of Windows Defender.

I tried changing by *`GPEDIT.msc` → Windows Defender → scan → Turn on removal of items from scan history → set the days to 1*.
In this case, it stores the data for 1 day.

Also I tried `Remove-MpThreat` cmdlet, but it did not clear the history.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to remove the history details